# grub not detecting windows 8

Tags: 12.04, grub2, windows-8

I have a dell inspiron 5520. I had installed windows 8 and have ubuntu 12.04 installed in a different partition. I installed grub but it was not showing windows 8. So i added

```
menuentry "Windows 8" {

set root = "(hd0,4)"

  chainloader +1

  }
```

in `/etc/grub.d/40_custom`. Now, I see Windows 8 option but it says `error-invalid selection` when I select it. Please help.

This is the output of `fdisk -l`:

```
/dev/sda1 * 16072 626807 305368 de Dell Utility
/dev/sda3 7645184 500201471 246278144 7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda4 500203518 976771071 238283777 f W95 Ext'd (LBA)
Partition 4 does not start on physical sector boundary.
/dev/sda5 500203520 870275071 185035776 7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda6 870277120 886276095 7999488 82 Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/sda7 886278144 976771071 45246464 83 Linux
```

Comment: Found useful doc about custom menu entries here https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/CustomMenus#Sample_Menuentries

Answer (score 1):

Please notice that grub's hd numbering starts with 0! In your case:

```
/dev/sda1 is (hd0,0)
/dev/sda3 is (hd0,1)
/dev/sda4 is (hd0,2)
/dev/sda5 is (hd0,3)
/dev/sda6 is (hd0,4)
/dev/sda7 is (hd0,5)
```

As you can see, you are trying to chainload the swap partition! Choose the correct partition's setting, and it will work.